# Search Results goes up when scrolling down in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a search box where users can search for products. This drop down shows all of the products. I am trying to Scroll down the list using scroller but when i scroll down it goes up

```
  if ($('#search_product').length) {
        //Add Product
        $('#search_product')
            .autocomplete({
                source: function(request, response) {
                    var price_group = '';
                    var search_fields = [];
                    $('.search_fields:checked').each(function(i){
                      search_fields[i] = $(this).val();
                    });

                    if ($('#price_group').length > 0) {
                        price_group = $('#price_group').val();
                    }
                    $.getJSON(
                        '/products/list',
                        {
                            price_group: price_group,
                            location_id: $('input#location_id').val(),
                            term: request.term,
                            not_for_selling: 0,
                            search_fields: search_fields
                        },
                        response
                    );
                },
                minLength: 2,
                response: function(event, ui) {
                    if (ui.content.length == 1) {
                        ui.item = ui.content[0];
                        if ((ui.item.enable_stock == 1 && ui.item.qty_available > 0) || 
                                (ui.item.enable_stock == 0)) {
                            $(this)
                                .data('ui-autocomplete')
                                ._trigger('select', 'autocompleteselect', ui);
                            $(this).autocomplete('close');
                        }
                    } else if (ui.content.length == 0) {
                        toastr.error(LANG.no_products_found);
                        $('input#search_product').select();
                    }
                },
                focus: function(event, ui) {
                    if (ui.item.qty_available <= 0) {
                        return false;
                    }
                },
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    var searched_term = $(this).val();
                    var is_overselling_allowed = false;
                    if($('input#is_overselling_allowed').length) {
                        is_overselling_allowed = true;
                    }

                    if (ui.item.enable_stock != 1 || ui.item.qty_available > 0 || is_overselling_allowed) {
                        $(this).val(null);

                        //Pre select lot number only if the searched term is same as the lot number
                        var purchase_line_id = ui.item.purchase_line_id && searched_term == ui.item.lot_number ? ui.item.purchase_line_id : null;
                        pos_product_row(ui.item.variation_id, purchase_line_id);
                    } else {
                        alert(LANG.out_of_stock);
                    }
                },
            })
            .autocomplete('instance')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
                var is_overselling_allowed = false;
                if($('input#is_overselling_allowed').length) {
                    is_overselling_allowed = true;
                }
            if (item.enable_stock == 1 && item.qty_available <= 0 && !is_overselling_allowed) {
                var string = '<li class="ui-state-disabled">' + item.name;
                if (item.type == 'variable') {
                    string += '-' + item.variation;
                }
                var selling_price = item.selling_price;
                if (item.variation_group_price) {
                    selling_price = item.variation_group_price;
                }
                string +=
                    ' (' +
                    item.sub_sku +
                    ')' +
                    '<br> Price: ' +
                    selling_price +
                    ' (Out of stock) </li>';
                return $(string).appendTo(ul);
            } else {
                var string = '<div class="col-md-10">' + item.name;
                if (item.type == 'variable') {
                    string += '-' + item.variation;
                }

                var selling_price = item.selling_price;
                if (item.variation_group_price) {
                    selling_price = item.variation_group_price;
                }

                string += ' (' + item.sub_sku + ')' + '<br> Price: ' + selling_price;
                if (item.enable_stock == 1) {
                    var qty_available = __currency_trans_from_en(item.qty_available, false, false, __currency_precision, true);
                    string += ' - ' + qty_available + item.unit;
                }
                string += '</div>';
                
                string += '<div class="col-md-2" style="text-align:right"> <img src="' + item.image_url + '" width="100" hight="100"> </div>'; 
 
                return $('<li>')
                    .append(string)
                    .appendTo(ul);
            }
        };
    }
```

Am not sure where am going wrong. Any help is appreciated. when i try to scroll down it allows scrolling but it goes to top instantly top first few results

Thanks in advance.

Laravel Blade Code

```
{!! Form::text('search_product', null, ['class' => 'form-control mousetrap', 'id' => 'search_product', 'placeholder' => __('lang_v1.search_product_placeholder'),
                'disabled' => is_null($default_location)? true : false,
                'autofocus' => is_null($default_location)? false : true,
                ]); !!}
```

Comment: Please edit the question and add the HTML as well.

Comment: I am using it on Laravel Blade, I have Added the form